# Extract json values using just regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a description field that is embedded within json and I'm unable to utilize json libraries to parse this data.

I use `{0,23}` in order in attempt to extract first 23 characters of string, how to extract entire value associated with description ?

```
   import re

    description = "'\description\" : \"this is a tesdt \n another test\" "

    re.findall(r'description(?:\w+){0,23}', description, re.IGNORECASE)
```

For above code just `['description']` is displayed

Comment: Use `{23}` instead of `{0, 23}`

Comment: There are no characters matching `\w` imrediately after `description` so this is completely expected. Perhaps you are looking for `.{0,23}`?

Comment: Even if you are unable to `import json` (but why??) using regex for this seems misdirected, especially if you are unfamiliar with regex.

Comment: It may be helpful to know why you can't use any JSON libraries.

Comment: What output should be?

Comment: @revo should be \"this is a tesdt \n another test\"

Comment: @blue-sky Do you want the backslash before the `"`?

Comment: In case the problem with JSON libraries is that the JSON is embedded in a larger document like a webpage and you don't know how to parse only the JSON, check out https://github.com/alexmojaki/jsonfinder

Comment: It's not *23 characters*. Where that number comes from?

Comment: @blue-sky I've completely edited my previous answer in response to your newly set conditions. Please check out the latest version.

Comment: This is a typical bad question. "Have some problem (which is not demonstrated in the question) and I want to solve it with a regex". A regex is obviously the wrong approach here.

Comment: Why does your sample 'JSON' start with (1) a single quote and (2) `\d`? Is it meant to be `"\"description\" : \"...\" "`?

Comment: Also is that an actual newline in your sample, or did you mean `\\n` (which would result in the JSON representation of a newline)? An actual newline would make the JSON invalid, perhaps that's why you're having trouble parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code out:

```
import re

description = "description\" : \"this is a tesdt \n another test\" "

result = re.findall(r'(?<=description")(?:\s*\:\s*)(".{0,23}?(?=")")', description, re.IGNORECASE+re.DOTALL)[0]

print(result)
```

Which gives you the result of:

```
"this is a tesdt 
 another test"
```

Which is essentially:

```
\"this is a tesdt \n another test\"
```

And is what you have asked for in the comments.

---

## Explanation -

`(?<=description")` is a positive look-behind that tells the regex to match the text preceded by `description"`
`(?:\s*\:\s*)` is a non-capturing group that tells the regex that `description"` will be followed by zero-or-more spaces, a colon (`:`) and again zero-or-more spaces.
`(".{0,23}?(?=")")` is the actual match desired, which consists of a double-quotes (`"`), zero-to-twenty three characters, and a double-quotes (`"`) at the end.

Comment: how to match until a double quotes is met ?

Comment: @blue-sky You'll have to elaborate on that, because in your sample input, `description` is immediately followed by a double quotation mark.

Comment: Honestly, what's the point here? You encourage the OP to parse json with regular expressions?

Comment: @hek2mgl I apologize for using regex here, even though I have heard that using a JSON Library is better than regex in such cases, as comments in my previous answers. However, I know absolutely nothing about JSON, or its libraries, and I am accustomed to using regex. The question seemed simple enough, so I used regex in my answer.

Comment: @hek2mgl I thought that since the OP tagged the question with `regex`, he would be familiar with it, and I also saw some comments telling him to use JSON Libraries. So I thought I might as well add whatever limited information I knew as an answer, solve his problem, and then he would also be able to later learn about JSON Parsing.

Comment: But I'm sorry, I **really** don't know anything about JSON.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder You are fine ;) .. Well, I wouldn't have answered here.

Comment: @hek2mgl Perhaps you could add an answer using JSON, and tell him how it would be easier to use that instead of regex. I'm sure that would be better appreciated :)

Comment: I would, but unfortunately the OP didn't described their problem. There is no json to parse in the question.

Comment: This doesn't handle escaped quotes and also catches any that ends with `description`. On a side note, it doesn't seem like a great idea to answer a question about manually parsing a data format that you **really** don't know anything about.

Answer (score 0):

```
# First just creating some test JSON

import json

data = {
    'items': [
        {
            'description': 'A "good" thing',

            # This is ignored because I'm assuming we only want the exact key 'description'
            'full_description': 'Not a good thing'
        },
        {
            'description': 'Test some slashes: \\ \\\\ \" // \/ \n\r',
        },
    ]
}

j = json.dumps(data)

print(j)

# The actual code

import re

pattern = r'"description"\s*:\s*("(?:\\"|[^"])*?")'
descriptions = [

    # I'm using json.loads just to parse the matched string to interpret
    # escapes properly. If this is not acceptable then ast.literal_eval
    # will probably also work
    json.loads(d)
    for d in re.findall(pattern, j)]

# Testing that it works

assert descriptions == [item['description'] for item in data['items']]
```

Comment: Honestly, what's the point here? You encourage the OP to parse json with regular expressions?